# Nesting issue with Bootstrap 3 grid system

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-grid

I have the following code in an .aspx page

```css
.cDiv {
  background-color: gray;
}

.tColor {
  background-color:yellow;
}

.tColor2 {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 tColor">
        Level 1: .col-sm-9
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 tColor2">
                  Level 2: .col-sm-6
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 cDiv">
                  Level 2: .col-sm-6
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the second column gets wider than its parent. I get the following result

[image]

Comment: You have to delete second row.

Comment: I need a nested row why should I delete it

Comment: Delete the second `.row` and lower the `.col-sm-6` to like `.col-sm-3` if possible

Comment: It works for me.. Are you using 3.3.7 version of bootstrap?

Comment: why .col-sm-6 is not working. I am using this code snippet from bootstrap site https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-nesting in there they have used .col-sm-6.

Comment: Are you added bootstrap css in your code? because it's working fine here:https://jsfiddle.net/bbze50sv/

Comment: it is working in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36684/)..

Comment: maybe you didn't properly include your bootstrap..

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to include bootstrap css

```css
.cDiv {
  background-color: gray;
}

.tColor {
  background-color:yellow;
}

.tColor2 {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 tColor">
        Level 1: .col-sm-9
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 tColor2">
                  Level 2: .col-sm-6
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 cDiv">
                  Level 2: .col-sm-6
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bbze50sv/)

Comment: Why bootstrap.css is not working I had added bootstrap.css link to my page but it was not working but win I included the bootstrap.min.css it worked. Its CDN also worked fine. Why ??

Comment: are you added css file from local or using external link?

Comment: I have added it locally